# Install SQL Server Express without administration rights

Tags: installation, sql-server-express

Is there a way to install SQL Server Express without administration right?

Is there a portable version?

(I need to test SQL Server on my computer before using the server but I don't have administration right. so I cannot install it. I search a way to bypassed my problem)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You are installing a program and making service and registry changes, etc. You need to run setup as an account that has local administrative rights. No workaround to this that wouldn't involve some back door into administrative rights.

Best bet is to ask for someone to temporarily give you the rights or install it for you.

Source: The Microsoft SQL Server books online article for [how to install SQL Server 2008 R2Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143219.aspx)

Comment: In 2018, the recommended way to solve this would be to install inside a virtual machine.

Comment: If in 2018 they give you administrative rights over your VM or the ability to create your own VM. Actually in 2018, the way to do it would be to go into AWS or Azure and spin up your own VM and try it yourself and deallocate the VM the next day, and you'll spend the same price as a double mocha something no fat with whip at one of them coffee shops.